# Making popver disappear on click of anywhere else than popover

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I am made one popover.
i want to make sure that the popover should close if the user click anywhere else than popover.
HTML code-
         New quote1
           New quote
            
               
               New quote

Js code-

```
    angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.selectedItems = {quote : {label : 'You ngModal now works'}};

    $scope.newQuote = function(){
        alert('It works');
    }
})
.directive('popover', function($compile){
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function(scope, elem){

            var content = $("#popover-content").html();
            var compileContent = $compile(content)(scope);
            var title = $("#popover-head").html();
            var options = {
                content: compileContent,
                html: true,
                title: title
            };

            $(elem).popover(options);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the link to jsfiddle-[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Rhul/qkwdnjdy/4/)

Comment: why don't you use angular ui popover https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover and refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30810676/2435473

Comment: i have added lot of functionality in this popover.At last min i cant change the popover.Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include entire BootstrapUI for only popover then you need to do two things. First of all, you need to set up click event listener on the body or document level and check if bubbled event originates from popover container. Then it's also important the you prevent event bubbling in case of the directive element click, so popover doesn't get closed right after opening.

Entire directive code:

```
.directive('popover', function($compile) {

    $('body').on('click', function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).parents('.popover.in').length) { 
            $('.popover').popover('hide');
        }
    });

    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function(scope, elem){

            var content = $("#popover-content").html();
            var compileContent = $compile(content)(scope);
            var title = $("#popover-head").html();
            var options = {
                content: compileContent,
                html: true,
                title: title
            };

            $(elem).popover(options).click(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Btw, don't put `$('body').on('click'` in directive's link function: you don't want to bind one more handler each time directive is linked.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qkwdnjdy/5/

Comment: this jsfiddle is working only when we are clicking in the same row where the popover button is present...not for anywhere else...

Comment: Because the body is too short. You can either make body stretch (`html, body {height: 100%}`) or delegate click to document. http://jsfiddle.net/qkwdnjdy/6/

Answer (score -1):

you can add `data-trigger="focus"` attribute to your anchor tag . it will do the needful. Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkwdnjdy/7/)